# How to make code more readable and simpler

Tags: javascript, simplify, readability, code-cleanup, code-readability

I have this simple code which i have reduced to as little lines and made as readable as possible. I feel i did a good job but was wandering if it is possible to reduce down further? Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks you

```
 const hasHourlyRate = hourly_price !== null;
 const hasDayRate = daily_price !== null;
 const hasMonthRate = monthly_price !== null;

 const ratesTypes = !desks
    ? null
    : hasHourlyRate & hasDayRate & hasMonthRate // If all rates are available
    ? [[1, 'Hourly'], [2, 'Day Pass'], [3, 'Monthly Pass']]
    : hasHourlyRate & hasDayRate & !hasMonthRate // If only hourly and daily are available
    ? [[1, 'Hourly'], [2, 'Day Pass']]
    : hasHourlyRate & !hasDayRate & hasMonthRate // If only hourly and monthly are available
    ? [[1, 'Hourly'], [2, 'Monthly Pass']]
    : !hasHourlyRate & hasDayRate & hasMonthRate // If only daily and monthly are available
    ? [[1, 'Day Pass'], [2, 'Monthly Pass']]
    : hasHourlyRate & !hasDayRate & !hasMonthRate // If only hourly is available
    ? [[1, 'Hourly']]
    : !hasHourlyRate & hasDayRate & !hasMonthRate // If only daily is available
    ? [[1, 'Day Pass']]
    : !hasHourlyRate & !hasDayRate & hasMonthRate // If only monthly is available
    ? [[1, 'Monthly Pass']]
    : null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check each condition separately as such.

```
arr=[];
i=1;
if(hasHourlyRate){
    arr.push([i, "Hourly"]);
    i++;
}
if(hasDayRate){
    arr.push([i, "Day Pass"]);
    i++;
}
if(hasMonthRate){
    arr.push([i, "Monthly Pass"]);
    i++;
}
```

If you can get your values into an array to loop through that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can store some of your conditions as variables. You can also look at recursively checking all possible conditions.

This may help:
[Using recursion to find all possible combinations][1]

Memoization would speed up the process further.

May be a bit overkill so I'd look at storing your combinations in variables first.